# Popover transparent in IPAD simulator but not in device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, xcode5, popover

I have a popover in my app, a simple one with only a "textview" in it. I managed to make it transparent, that is, that only "thetext" shows, being totally transparent to the image below (image on view, not in the popover). Did this with this in `viewDidAppear`:

self.viewpoptexto.superview.superview.alpha = 0.9f;

The problem is, this works fine when i run the app in the simulator (IPAD, IPAD retina, IPAD retina 64bits), but running on the device, the popover shows a white background and stills get drawn.

XCODE 5 and IOS7.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the popover background color to clearColor.
[popover setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]